# String.IndexOf function giving incorrect position number for TextBox.Select

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I found a strange behavior in indexOf functionality in my code, My string input is from read from a text file, when I search some text in the firstline of the code indexOf function correctly identify the position of the sub-string, but if I search some text in the second line it returns one character after the exact match, if I search something in the 3rd line it is returning 2 character position after the exact match, this is changing in the same pattern with every new line. I don't know why this is happening, I need to find a way to get the exact same position of the text.

My Code:

```
string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filename);
string display_string = "";
txtOriginalText.Text = fileContent;

HighlightText(fileContent.IndexOf("projection"), 5, Color.Aqua);
display_string += fileContent.IndexOf("projection").ToString() + '\n';

HighlightText(fileContent.IndexOf("component"), 5, Color.LightGreen);
display_string += fileContent.IndexOf("component").ToString() + '\n';

HighlightText(fileContent.IndexOf("layer"), 5, Color.Pink);
display_string += fileContent.IndexOf("layer").ToString() + '\n';

txtModifiedText.Text = display_string;
```

Highlight function

```
   private void HighlightText(int startIndex, int textLength, Color state)
    {
        txtOriginalText.Select(startIndex, textLength);
        txtOriginalText.SelectionBackColor = state;
    }
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: @RenéVogt it is a richtextbox

Comment: In Windows new line is 2 characters `\r\n`.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] with hard-coded data (no need for an actual file).

Comment: @Rafal but does it do anything with indexOf function or my code?

Comment: `((int)fileContent[32]) == 13`(`\r`) and `((int)fileContent[33]) == 10`(`\n`)

Comment: @CharlesRajendran: Well if the string contains `\r\n` but the Select method counts each line break as a single character, that would explain everything.

Comment: Maybe search in the controls Text property instead of the file contents.

Comment: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com) see here new line character has a ASCII value of 10(dec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this with a `RichTextBox`:

```
richTextBox1.Text = "test\r\ntest\r\ntest\r\n";
```

When you debug and check `richTextBox1.Text` after that line, its value is `"test\ntest\ntest\n"`.

So it seems the `RichTextBox` removes the `\r` from your string (which as a Windows file content probably contains new line characters as `\r\n`).

As an immediate work around you should use `IndexOf` on `txtOriginalText.Text` instead of `fileContent`.

Comment: another workaround:`txtOriginalText.Text=fileContent; fileContent=txtOriginalText.Text;` Strange but with a comment explains everything